# Java DESede encrypt, OpenSSL equivalent

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl, des

I'm using DESede encryptation in Java and I want to make the same encryptation using  the OpenSSL's API in C++.

Java code:

```
    String secretKey = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx";

    byte[] bytes = secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "DESede");

    Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    String input = "holahola1"; 

    byte[] utf8 = input.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8); // Encrypt
```

output: [94, -45, 64, -105, 99, -55, 99, -42, 95, 122, 72, 117, -119, 95, -43, 40]

C++ code:

```
    unsigned char intext[256], outtext[256];

    memset(intext, 0, sizeof(intext));
    memset(outtext, 0, sizeof(outtext));

    char *output = (char *)outtext;
    DES_key_schedule keyschedc1;
    DES_key_schedule keyschedc2;
    DES_key_schedule keyschedc3;
    DES_cblock keyc1;
    DES_cblock keyc2;
    DES_cblock keyc3;

    DES_string_to_key("abcdefgh", &keyc1);
    DES_string_to_key("ijklmnop", &keyc2);
    DES_string_to_key("qrstuvwx", &keyc3);
    DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)keyc1, &keyschedc1);
    DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)keyc2, &keyschedc2);
    DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)keyc3, &keyschedc3); 

    strcpy((char *)intext, "holahola1");

    for (int i=0; i<16; i += 8)
    {
        DES_ecb3_encrypt((DES_cblock *)(intext + i),
                        (DES_cblock *)(outtext + i), 
                        &keyschedc1, &keyschedc2, 
                        &keyschedc3,DES_ENCRYPT);
    }
```

output: [30 55 9 -58 -18 -65 -66 123 -32 72 30 110 120 69 101 -81]

What's wrong? Can someone help me? Thanks!.

Comment: Just curious why anyone would use DES for encryption?

Comment: I'm working with a new Jabber client, and I need guard the compatibility with the older client.

Comment: You are using single DES in the C++ code.

Comment: DESede is sometimes called 3DES.  You are also using ECB , which is insecure.  You need to ensure that both Java and C++ are using a better mode, such as CBC.

Comment: Hi rosuum, I'm pretty sure that Java is using ECB mode, beacuse CBC mode need a init vector, and DESede, doesn't requests me this vector.

Comment: Chris, Java will use a default IV if it is not supplied. To quote: "If this cipher requires any algorithm parameters that cannot be derived from the given key, the underlying cipher implementation is supposed to generate the required parameters itself (using provider-specific default or random values) if it is being initialized for encryption or key wrapping, and raise an InvalidKeyException if it is being initialized for decryption or key unwrapping. The generated parameters can be retrieved using getParameters or getIV (if the parameter is an IV)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Java DESede encryption, uses a triple DES with ecb mode, and uses a PKCS#5 padding. So, I fill my text, using PKCS#5, and it solve all.

Example C++ code:

```
unsigned char intext[256], outtext[256];

memset(intext, 0x07, sizeof(intext)); //PKCS#5 padding (See documentation)
memset(outtext, 0, sizeof(outtext));
char *output = (char *)outtext;

DES_key_schedule keyschedc1;
DES_key_schedule keyschedc2;
DES_key_schedule keyschedc3;
DES_cblock keyc1;
DES_cblock keyc2;
DES_cblock keyc3;

DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)"abcdefgh", &keyschedc1);
DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)"ijklmnop", &keyschedc2);
DES_set_key((DES_cblock *)"qrstuvwx", &keyschedc3); 

strcpy((char *)intext, "holahola1");

for (int i=0; i<16; i += 8)
{
    DES_ecb3_encrypt((DES_cblock *)(intext + i),
                    (DES_cblock *)(outtext + i), 
                    &keyschedc1, &keyschedc2, 
                    &keyschedc3,DES_ENCRYPT);
}
```

Comment: Please heed the advise of Rossum: your algorithm is not secure, you should at least use `"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`, not forgetting to use a random IV. If possible, use AES and/or some kind of integrity proctection.

Comment: Hi owlstead, I know that the algorithm is not secure, but I need it for compatibility with older version. Thank for you advice.

Comment: I have tested last example in C/C++ and see set first 8 bytes are identical to Java encryption but next 8 bytes do not identical: out: 0x5e 0xd3 0x40 0x97 0x63 0xc9 0x63 0xd6 0x2e 0x3d 0xa6 0xf6 0xb0 0x09 0xd7 0x19

Comment: The example works. i'm using it currently. It seems that the padding using in c++ and in java it's not equal, so be sure that java is using PKCS#5

Answer (score 1):

Try DES_ecb3_encrypt instead as you are using 3 separate keys.

Comment: Hi owlstead, I changed my C++ code, you can see the new code in the question, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bytes = secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "**DESede/PKCS#5**");
```